# Can we access session data on other pages on the server? (php)

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to use a session in other page from where I defined it how can I do it in php?

#### login.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($username))
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
?>

<h1>Webmaster Login</h1>

<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="username">
    <p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

That was where I defined my session now I want to use it as `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` on another page from login.php . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `session_start();` on all pages that set or need access to `$_SESSION`.

login.php

```
session_start();
//more code
```

another_page.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { /*something*/ }
```

Comment: *"now I want to use it as `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))` on another page from login.php . How can I do this?"*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, I already read that in the question.

Comment: *Personally,* I like using `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))` that way it checks if it's set and not empty; *but that's just me*. ;-)